# redirect http from content rules

Tags: http, redirect, filtering

I would like to redirect HTTP client to multiples internal servers incoming from the same URL based on content.
The content is xml, I have a known IDs like Id_Client="xxxxxx"

so when

- Id_Client="xxxxxx" came I would like to redirect to internal server 1
- Id_Client="yyyyyy" came I would like to redirect to internal server 1
- all others to internal server 2

the string Id_Client="xxxxxx" is in the xml request body

I think I could write such a thing but I'm sure someone has already done, and it should be better than I could do.